# find nth fibonacci number where n can vary till 10^9

Tags: java, fibonacci, biginteger

//  i was trying to find (n^n)%1000000007 where n is the nth fibonacci term of the series.
     example : n=3  ans 4 (2^2)

```
 public class Sol_Big {
 public static void main(String args[])
{  
       int n =10000000;
       BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO;
       BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
       BigInteger c = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
       BigInteger MOD = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000007);

       for (int j=2 ; j<=n ; j++)
       {
           c =  a.add(b);
           c=c.mod( MOD);
           a = b.mod(MOD);
           b = c.mod(MOD);
       }
        System.out.println(c);
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        result = c.modPow(c, MOD);
        int intval = result.intValue();
        System.out.println( intval);

      }
}
```

// my code is working for 10^7 input but for 10^8 and onward it is exceeding time limit....

Comment: Its will be good  idea to use stringbuffer for this purpose. do manipulation in sr=tring buffer and return final string.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to notice that you can calculate the Fibonacci numbers using matrix multiplication:

```
| 0 1 |   | a |   | b     |
| 1 1 | * | b | = | a + b |
```

With this knowledge, we can calulate the n-th Fibonacci number:

```
| 0 1 |^n   | 0 |
| 1 1 |   * | 1 |
```

Because matrix multiplication is associative, we can efficiently calculate m^n.

- If `n` is even, `m^n = m^(n/2) * m^(n/2)`
- If `n` is odd, `m^n = m^((n-1)/2)) * m^((n-1)/2)) * m`

Note that we need the same thing twice, but we only have to compute it once.
This makes it possible to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number in `O(log n)`.

I leave it to you to write the code.